# zend\form\element\select with multiple attribute: how to override default notEmpty validation error?

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-validate

My `Zend\Form` includes a `Zend\Form\Element\Select` with the attribute `'multiple' => 'multiple'` and a `NotEmpty` validator with a custom `isEmpty` error message. 
With the multiple attribute set, when I submit the form without selecting any options, I get the default *"Value is required..."* error message rather than my own. 
When I remove the `multiple` attribute, I get the desired behavior, i.e., my custom error message.

So, what I am doing wrong?

Here is the quick-and-dirty test, with everything stuffed into my controller action for the sake of demonstration:

```
public function testAction() {

    $form = new \Zend\Form\Form;
    $factory = new \Zend\InputFilter\Factory;
    $form->add(
        [
            'name' => 'select',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'attributes' => [
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
            ],
            'options' =>[
                'value_options' => ['' => '', 1 => "one", 2 => "two", 3 => "three"],
            ] 
        ]

    );
    $filter = $factory->createInputFilter([
        'select' => [
            'name' => 'select',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => 'StringTrim',],
            ],
            'validators' => [[
                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                'options' => ['messages' => ['isEmpty'=> 'all Dharmas are forms of Emptiness']],
            ]],
        ]
    ]);
    $form->setInputFilter($filter);
    $form->add(['name'=> 'submit','type'=> 'submit', 'attributes'=> ['value'=> 'submit']]);
    $form->setAttribute('action','/my-project/index/test')
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('my-project/index/test')
        ->setVariables(['form' => $form]);
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->params()->fromPost();
        $form->setData($data);
        print_r($data); // just making sure, for sanity's sake
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            echo "valid!";
        } else {
            echo "validation failed.";
        }
    }
    return $view;
}
```

Just for the record, here is the view, although I know (from dumping the error messages) that the issue is not here:

```
<?php 
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCollection($form);
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I just tryed to run your code (removing the `setAttribute` method call, which was causing a 500) and I can see the correct error message...

Comment: really?! Fascinating. I was just coming back here to add that I am using ZF 2.5.1. And you?

btw I will update the code to correct the ->setAttribute() which I meant to call on the $form, not the $view

Comment: I am using version 2.5.1 too... very weird...

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with the fact that setting the `multiple` field will cause the `Select` class to change the validator.

You can see that [here on line 227 in the `getValidator` method of the `Zend\Form\Element\Select` class](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Element/Select.php#L227).

```
$validator = new ExplodeValidator([
    'validator'      => $validator,
    'valueDelimiter' => null, // skip explode if only one value
]);
```

The `ExplodeValidator` [will validate each value independently](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/Explode.php#L166) with the validator that you provided and this probably leads to the unexpected *"Value is required..."* error message. Most likely the validator will end up [on line 186](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/Explode.php#L186) setting `$values` as an array containing an empty string.

I think if you want to get your custom message is to set `required => false` and `'allow_empty' => false` for your validator. In your case I think this should not be a problem...

Comment: Well, setting `required => false` and `allow_empty => false` results in the input passing validation, as one would expect, so that doesn't do it. I will try to investigate what you're saying about ExplodeValidator. Thanks.

Comment: *"so that doesn't do it"* @David Why does it not do it? I don't get the problem. It will still validate and won't allow empty arrays for your multiple select list...

Comment: No, I'm talking about overriding the default NotEmpty validator's error message with my own -- that's what I have not been able to do (other than with crude hacks in the view layer).